# Highchart title to separate div of many charts

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, highcharts

I have several charts displayed in one div. Currently, i am just rendering the chart to this one div based on click.I want to hold the title of the chart in one separate div and it should be also in title.text property of highcharts.

Example for this

```
    <script src="http://code.highcharts.com/highcharts.js"></script>

<div id="container" style="height: 400px"></div>
<div id="title">Chart title</div>// here i want to hold title 
 <div id='some'>
    <select>
        <option value="volvo">Volvo</option>
        <option value="saab">Saab</option>
        <option value="opel">Opel</option>
        <option value="audi">Audi</option>
    </select>
    <select>
        <option value="more">More</option>
        <option value="lidl">Lidl</option>
        <option value="coop">COOP</option>
        <option value="ICA">IKA</option>
    </select>
</div>
```

Javascript code

```
 $(function () {
    $('#container').highcharts({
        chart: {
            plotBorderWidth: 1,
            marginLeft: 80
        },
        xAxis: {
            categories: ['Jan', 'Feb', 'Mar', 'Apr', 'May', 'Jun', 'Jul', 'Aug', 'Sep', 'Oct', 'Nov', 'Dec']
        },
        title: {
            useHTML:true,
            text:'Chart Title',
            align: 'left',
            x: 70
        },
        series: [{
            data: [29.9, 71.5, 106.4, 129.2, 144.0, 176.0, 135.6, 148.5, 216.4, 194.1, 95.6, 54.4]        
        }]
    });
});
```

fiddle is here http://jsfiddle.net/BETBk/113/

I want title.text property should have its title but it should hide from the display instead title will be displayed from div tag always.

Any help on this would be thankful.

Comment: Simple mockup would be great. Honestly, I'm not sure what you want to achieve, something like this: http://jsfiddle.net/BETBk/114/ ? Just one title? Then disable Highcharts built-in title.

Comment: This i know, in my case i have large title text and it wraps on to another divs. I just want to read this title in one div and will want go for div auto grow in case of large titles. If i do as the given fiddle by you. i would face problems in PDF downloads as it display empty in title place.

Comment: Do you refer Highcharts exporting module? In such case remember you can use `chartOptions` and enable that title only for exported chart:  http://jsfiddle.net/BETBk/116/ - remember, that exporting doesn't support HTML tags, only SVG.

Comment: Thanks, I just forgotten this little step.